# Почему данный код возвращает пустую строку?

Tags: c#, linq

Добрый день! Почему данный код возвращает пустую строку?

```
public class MyModel {

    public MyModel() {
        MyModel2= new List<MyModel2>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyModel2> MyModel2 {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string m = "";

    // Фрукты
    public virtual string Fruits {
        get {
            var mymodel2 = MyModel2.Select(x => x).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Id, kvp => kvp.Fruit);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<long, string> pair in mymodel2) {
                m = pair.Value.ToString();
            }

            return m;
        }
        set {
            var mymodel2 = MyModel2.Select(x => x).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Id, kvp => kvp.Fruit);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<long, string> pair in mymodel2) {
                m = pair.Value.ToString();
            }

            value = m;
        }
    }

}

public class MyModel2 {
    public MyModel2() {
        this.Id = 1;
        this.Fruit = "Ананас";
    }

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Fruit {get; set;}
}
```

Как вернуть, получить слово Ананас из класса `MyModel2`, значение свойства `string Fruit`?

Comment: @Demon а что это творчество  должно возвращать по-вашему, если свойство MyModel2 - это пустой список?

    MyModel2= new List<MyModel2>()

 Более того, этот код даже не компилируется (ряд мелких ошибок и опечаток).

Comment: Почему это свойство пустой список? Разве этот список не содержит значения this.Id = 1; this.Fruit = "Ананас"? Как тогда его заполнить значениями свойств Id и Fruit класса Model2?

Comment: @Demon вы пожалуйста не обижайтесь, но у вас очень большие пробелы в понимании основ самого языка. Отсюда непонимание элементарных вещей, которое вы демонстрируете как в этом вопросе, так и в предыдущих, и отсюда же ваша пагубная любовь к конструированию велосипедов и несоблюдение принципа KISS. 

Ваш список пуст. Id = 1 и Fruit = "Ананас" - это не содержимое списка. Это инициализация членов класса MyModel2. Чтобы пользоваться этими значениями, вам необходимо создать экземпляр этого класса, который вы нигде не создаете. new List<MyModel2>() - это создание списка MyModel2, а не самого MyModel2

Comment: ok. я создам экземпляр классса MyModel2, MyModel2 mymodel = new MyModel2; как мне теперь добавить экземпляр класса в список MyModel2 и получить значение его свойства, если у списка MyModel2 нет метода Add? Через Select не получается это сделать.

Comment: мне нужен Ienumerable

Comment: а что по-вашему, список не является IEnumerable? В крайнем случае, можете написать свой метод добавления элемента, который сможет решить эту задачу. Но это будет довольно корявое решение

Comment: List и Ienumerable это вообще то разные списки

Comment: - Я, кажется, понял, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Вы хотите, чтобы в первой (внешней) модели у вас было свойство, выполняющее проекцию списка вторых моделей в названия фруктов.

- Откинув мысли о том, зачем это вообще нужно, это можно сделать так: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6493019

- Лично я бы порекомендовал вам порешать ваши задачи без использования свойств и `LINQ` вообще — у меня сложилось впечатление, что сейчас IDE пишет код за вас, а не наоборот. Напишите весь код с помощью явных вызовов методов и конструкторов, а уже потом, при желании, используйте современные возможности языка.

Comment: >List и Ienumerable это вообще то разные списки

@Demon учите матчасть и не говорите чепухи. IEnumerable - это вообще не список. Но List<T> - это реализация интерфейса IEnumerable<T>, поэтому List<T> - это IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @Demon может вы все же потрудитесь адекватно и грамотно объяснить, для чего это нужно? Я более чем уверен, что для вашей задачи есть более правильное и простое решение, которое вы почему-то не хотите использовать, предпочитая писать невесть что. Я правильно вас понял, что вам нужен метод делающий что-то вроде этого: 

    string st = model.MagicMethod(fruits); // принимает последовательность "фруктов" и возвращает например "апельсин"

Тогда вопрос: как должна выполняться проекция из нескольких "фруктов" в один "апельсин"?  По каким правилам? Что должно быть в результате, если "фрукты" разные?

Comment: @Demon Ну, например, вы можете это сделать, введя конструкторы без параметров.